# The Jigsaw Code Puzzle

Tags: code-challenge, source-layout, answer-chaining

> This is an answer-dependent challenge! The order of answers matters, and your exact task depends on the last answer that was posted. You might want to [sort the answers *by oldest*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44966/the-jigsaw-code-puzzle?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

Let's piece together some code! Here are 1920 random (printable ASCII) characters. Think of them as a big heap of unsorted jigsaw puzzle pieces still in the box:

```
L-^=v^Ej2tW8OxNOIecSt4m}tji2O%YRJ;PJ!M|0*oO77$*Rs&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x)u)IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j."(6U|{[UY@`lrCSJ`u0RHX!1z7f,v}n=GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz]iC<](:+FF?Ay'vX~h5QMF)0vaXk1sk@p
Zj).{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u<_-4B^A>I8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%`@:%H3wPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zip
{[ovg:6EpCT&'+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?<}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[F1F=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{"G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4Z0G4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{!m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^2mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{DZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iiP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2H*Az%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(d0y+UAr*sQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI#<`O$o#4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=8QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\']3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKGs5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;2'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`:[K:CY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{57#+2,*%]>p~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0"v1r+9fv;5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ93#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B!H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|R6rB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

The "floor" we're puzzling on is initially just a 96x20 grid of spaces (code point 0x20). Each answer may move around adjacent blocks of pieces, and choose up to 10 puzzle pieces (characters) and add them to the puzzle to create a new program. That program must print the number of your answer (numbered sequentially, starting from 1).

### Answering

The key thing to understand about this challenge is that **only one person can answer at a time and each answer depends on the one before it**.

There should never be two answers with the same number **N**. If two people happen to simultaneously answer for some **N**, the one who answered later (even if it's a few seconds difference) should graciously delete their answer.

To make this run a bit smoother, try to stick to the following steps when posting your answer:

- Make sure that someone has independently verified the correctness of the previous answer (and left a corresponding comment).
- Take the previous "puzzle floor" and "box of pieces". You may move any adjacent block of characters on the puzzle floor around freely *as a unit* (characters are adjacent if they touch along the horizontal or vertical direction). Adjacent blocks cannot be split up again. Examples on a 5x4 grid:

  ```
  Last answer:     Valid:        Invalid:

  |a  bc|          |d  g |       |a  bc|          |  bc |          |a  bc|
  | d e |          |fa bc|       |d  e |   -or-   |d e  |   -or-   |   e |
  | f  g|          |   e |       | f  g|          |f  g |          |df g |
  |  h  |          |h    |       |  h  |          | h   |          |  h  |
  ```

  <sup>In the valid example, `a` was moved one step down and right. The `df` block was moved to the top left. The `bce` block was moved down by 1. The `g` was move two up and one to the left. The `h` block was moved all the way to the left.

  In the first invalid example `df` has been separated. In the second, `a` has been removed. In the third, `df` has been rotated.</sup>

  Next, remove **at least 1 and up to 10** characters from the "box of pieces" and choose that many spaces on the "puzzle floor", which you'll replace by those characters. This is your submitted program. Please include both the new "puzzle floor" and "box of pieces" in your answer.
- Post your answer in the following format:

  ```
  # N. [Language], [number of blocks moved], [number of pieces added]

      [grid that is your program]

  ### Remaining pieces:

      [grid of remaining characters]

  [notes, explanation, observations, whatever]
  ```

  where `N` is the number of your answer.

  **This is absolutely vital to the challenge!** I've provided a dashboard tool for the challenge to help with the bookkeeping, and it relies on the above template. (See bottom of the post.)
- Please include the vertical bars at the sides of puzzle floor, because otherwise, Stack Exchange won't display empty lines. These two columns are never to be considered part of the code.
- Another user should now review your submission and leave a comment "Correctness verified" if your answer follows all the rules (see below). If it doesn't, they should leave a comment pointing out any flaws. You've then got *15 minutes* to fix those issues. If you don't, your answer will be deemed invalid, should be deleted, and someone else may post a follow-up answer to the previous one. (If this happens, you're free to submit a new answer any time.)

These regulations may seem rather strict, but they are necessary to avoid invalid answers somewhere up the chain.

### The Rules

- **A user may only submit one answer per 4 hour period.** (This is to prevent users from constantly watching the question and answering as much as possible.)
- A user may not submit two answers in a row. (e.g. since I submitted answer 1 I can't do answer 2, but I could do 3.)
- **No language may be used more than once!** Different versions of the same language count as the same language. Languages count as distinct if they are traditionally called by two different names. (There may be some ambiguities here but don't let that ruin the contest.)
- **Do not edit answers that have been verified.**
- Should a mistake be discovered *earlier* in the chain (i.e. after follow-up answers have been posted), the offending answer should be deleted. *However*, all answers that have been posted since should *not* be changed to reflect this.
- Your program has to print `N`, the number of your answer, to STDOUT or closest alternative. It has to be a full program and must not assume a REPL environment.
- You may or may not print a trailing newline.
- Let **M** be the number of *blocks* you moved for your answer (no matter how far) and **P** the number of characters you added to the puzzle floor, the score of your answer will be **10 + N - M - P**. As a 5x4 example, if your answer changed the puzzle floor as follows

  ```
  |a  bc|         |a ij |
  | d e |   -->   | d bc|
  | f  g|         | f eg|
  |  h  |         | h  k|
  ```

  your score would be **10 + N - 2 - 3 = N + 5**, because two blocks were moved (`h` and `bce`) and three characters were added (`i`, `j` and `k`).
- **The winner** will be the user who accumulates the greatest number of points across their answers. In case of tie, the user with the latest answer wins. I will accept the winner's latest answer.
- In the unlikely event that all characters will be used up, the challenge ends.

### Dashboard

Here is a little Dashboard tool, which should help with the necessary bookkeeping for this type of challenge.

It displays the current status of the challenge - in particular, if there are conflicting answers, if an answer needs to be verified, or if the next answer can be posted.

It also produces a list of all languages that have been used, as well as a leaderboard of all users. Please stick to the answer format above, so the dashboard can read out the relevant strings from your answers. Otherwise you might not be included in the leaderboard.

Please let me know ([ideally in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)) if you spot any bugs or have some ideas how the usefulness of the tool could be improved.

```js
function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentsUrl(e,t){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+e+"/comments?page="+t+"&pagesize=100&order=asc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){$.ajax({url:answersUrl(page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:true,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items);if(e.has_more)getAnswers();else{page=1;getFinalComments()}}})}function getFinalComments(){answers=answers.filter(shouldHaveHeading);answers=answers.filter(shouldHaveScore);console.log(answers);$.ajax({url:commentsUrl(answers[0].answer_id,page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:true,success:function(e){comments.push.apply(comments,e.items);if(e.has_more)getAnswers();else process()}})}function shouldHaveHeading(e){var t=false;try{t|=/^(#|&lt;h).*/.test(e.body_markdown);t|=["-","="].indexOf(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[1][0])>-1}catch(n){}return t}function shouldHaveScore(e){var t=false;try{t|=HEADER_REG.test(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0])}catch(n){}return t}function findDuplicates(e){var t=false;var n={};e.forEach(function(e){var r=e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(NUMBER_REG)[0];if(n[r])t=t||r;n[r]=true});return t}function hasBeenVerified(e,t){var n=false;t.forEach(function(t){n|=/correctness verified/i.test(t.body_markdown)&&e!=t.owner.user_id});return n}function userTimedOut(e){return NOW-e.creation_date*1e3<MSEC_PER_ANSWER}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function getAnswerScore(e,t,n){e=parseInt(e);t=parseInt(t);n=parseInt(n);return 10+e-t-n}function process(){$("#last-user").append(answers[0].owner.display_name);var e=answers.slice(1).filter(userTimedOut).map(getAuthorName).join(", ");if(e)$("#timed-out-users").append(e);else $("#timed-out-notice").hide();var t=answers[0].body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(NUMBER_REG)[0];var n=findDuplicates(answers);if(n){var r=$("#status-conflict-template").html();$("#challenge-status").append(r.replace("{{NUMBER}}",n));$("#challenge-status").addClass("conflict")}else if(!hasBeenVerified(answers[0].owner.user_id,comments)){var r=$("#status-verification-template").html();$("#challenge-status").append(r.replace("{{NUMBER}}",t));$("#challenge-status").addClass("verification")}else{var r=$("#status-next-template").html();$("#challenge-status").append(r.replace("{{NUMBER}}",t).replace("{{NEXT}}",parseInt(t)+1));$("#challenge-status").addClass("next")}var i={};var s={};var o=[];answers.forEach(function(e){var t=e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0];var n=$("#answer-template").html();var r=t.match(HEADER_REG)||[0,-1,"",0,0];var u=r[1];var a=r[2];var f=r[3];var l=r[4];var c=getAnswerScore(u,f,l);var h=getAuthorName(e);n=n.replace("{{NAME}}",h).replace("{{NUMBER}}",u).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",a).replace("{{MOVED}}",f).replace("{{ADDED}}",l).replace("{{SCORE}}",c).replace("{{LINK}}",e.share_link);n=$(n);$("#answers").append(n);i[h]=(i[h]||0)+c;s[h]=(s[h]||0)+1;o.push({lang:a,link:e.share_link})});var u=[];for(var a in i)if(i.hasOwnProperty(a)){u.push({name:a,numAnswers:s[a],score:i[a]})}u.sort(function(e,t){return t.score-e.score});var f=1;u.forEach(function(e){var t=$("#user-template").html();t=t.replace("{{NAME}}",e.name).replace("{{NUMBER}}",f++).replace("{{COUNT}}",e.numAnswers).replace("{{SCORE}}",e.score);t=$(t);$("#users").append(t)});o.sort(function(e,t){return e.lang.localeCompare(t.lang)});o.forEach(function(e){var t=$("#lang-template").html();t=t.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.lang).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link);t=$(t);$("#lang-list").append(t)})}var QUESTION_ID=44966;var ANSWER_FILTER="!*cCFgu5yS6BFQP8Z)xIZ.qGoikO4jB.Ahv_g-";var COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A497Z2O1kEH(Of5MUPK";var HOURS_PER_ANSWER=4;var MSEC_PER_ANSWER=HOURS_PER_ANSWER*60*60*1e3;var NOW=Date.now();var answers=[],comments=[],page=1;getAnswers();var NUMBER_REG=/\d+/;var HEADER_REG=/(\d+)[.]\s*([^,]*[^,\s])\s*,[^,\d]*(\d+)[^,\d]*,[^,\d]*(\d+)/
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}  #challenge-status {   font-weight: bold;   padding:  10px;   width: 800px; }  #blocked-users {   padding:  10px;   width: 800px; }  .conflict {   background: #994343;   color: white; }  .verification {   background: #FFDB12; }  .next {   background: #75FF6E; }  #last-user, #timed-out-users {   font-weight: bold; }  #answer-list {   padding: 10px;   width: 350px;   float: left; }  #leaderboard {   padding: 10px;   width: 280px;   float: left; }  #languages {   padding: 10px;   width: 130px;   float: left; }  table thead {   font-weight: bold; }  table td {   padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="challenge-status">  </div> <div id="blocked-users"> User <span id="last-user"></span> has posted the last answer, and may not post the next one. <div id="timed-out-notice"><span id="timed-out-users"></span> have answered within the last four hours and may not answer again yet. (If a user appears in this list twice, they must have answered twice within four hours!)</div> </div> <div id="answer-list">   <h2>List of Answers (newest first)</h2>   <table class="answer-list">     <thead>       <tr><td>No.</td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>M</td><td>P</td><td>Score</td></tr>     </thead>     <tbody id="answers">      </tbody>   </table> </div> <div id="leaderboard">   <h2>Leaderboard</h2>   <table class="leaderboard">     <thead>       <tr><td>No.</td><td>User</td><td>Answers</td><td>Score</td></tr>     </thead>     <tbody id="users">      </tbody>   </table> </div> <div id="languages">   <h2>Languages</h2>   <table class="languages">     <tbody id="lang-list">      </tbody>   </table> </div> <table style="display: none">   <tbody id="answer-template">     <tr><td>{{NUMBER}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{MOVED}}</td><td>{{ADDED}}</td><td>{{SCORE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>   </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none">   <tbody id="user-template">     <tr><td>{{NUMBER}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{COUNT}}</td><td>{{SCORE}}</td></tr>   </tbody> </table> <table style="display: none">   <tbody id="lang-template">     <tr><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{LANGUAGE}}</a></td></tr>   </tbody> </table> <div id="status-conflict-template" style="display: none">   There is more than one answer with number {{NUMBER}}!<br>   Please resolve this conflict before posting any further answer. </div> <div id="status-verification-template" style="display: none">   Answer {{NUMBER}} has not been verified!<br>   Please review the answer and post a comment reading "Correctness verified." on the answer if it is valid. Note that this has to be done by a different user than the author of the answer! </div> <div id="status-next-template" style="display: none">   Answer {{NUMBER}} has been verified!<br>   You may now post answer {{NEXT}}. </div>
```

#### Useful scripts

Here are two CJam scripts for your convenience. You can run them in the [online interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/).

1. To remove the first and last column from the puzzle floor (to get the actual code), paste it into STDIN, and run `qN/1f>Wf<N*`.
2. To pad your code out to a 96x20 rectangle and add the columns of vertical bars around it, run `qN/La20*+20<{96S*+96<'|\+'|+}%N*` on your code.
3. To find out which characters were removed from the box of pieces between two answers, paste both of them into STDIN (without an empty line in between), and run

   ```
   qS-N/20/{:+}%94,\f{\33+c_@\f/:,~-_0<{N"Added character: "@;@N}{*}?}
   ```

   It will also show if characters were *added* (not how many though).

If someone wants to reimplement these as Stack Snippets, I'm happy to add them to this post.

Comment: Sort by oldest is useful here.

Comment: So, we must stop our language from processing other characters (make them comments for example), and add code to send an integer to stdout using 10 new characters? I don't think Python will do well here. The 2 dimensional and golf languages should be interesting.

Comment: @CarpetPython Yes, the entire "puzzle floor" has to be run as your code, so you may have to comment out existing code. That shouldn't be too hard right now though, since you could just collect all the unwanted blocks into one line, prepend and prepend a single-line comment. By the time this gets annoying, I'm sure we'll have run out of non-esoteric languages anyway. ;)

Answer (score 5):

## 7. GolfScript, 1 moved, 1 added

```
|  6#                                      `.3i                                                 !|
|) :"                                                                                            |
|                                                                                                |
|              #               $>                              0            <<                   |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|print                                02                      **         2                       |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp 5                                                                            |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
```

#### Remaining Pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2tW8OxNOIecSt4m} j O%YRJ;PJ!M|0*oO77*Rs&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x)u)IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|{[UY@`l CSJ`u0RHX!1z7f,v} =GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz] C<](:+FF?Ay'vX~h5QMF)0vaXk1sk@p
Zj.{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zip
{[ovg:6E CT&'+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[F1F=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI <`O$o 4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=8QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\']3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;2'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0"v1r+9fv;5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ93#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B!H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

`#` is a single-line comment. Then `)` increments the 6 to 7. And the unmatched `"` acts to comment out the rest of the code. If the `"` *was* matched, then `:` would assign the value `7` to whatever string comes after it, so the `:"` part is valid syntax. As an example, if you had `5:"a"`, then writing `"a"` would actually push `5` onto the stack instead of the string (that is some serious magic).

But in this case, the interpreter just stops when it finds that the quote isn't matched.

[Tested with the online interpreter.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/)

Comment: I like the one-eyebrowed sadface `) :"`

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 3):

## 2. Prelude, 0 moved, 2 added

The program should be executed with numeric output mode.

```
|2                                                                                              !|
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                              $>                                           <<                   |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                     0                       **                                 |
|                                                 0                                              |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
```

**Remaining Pieces**

```
L-^=v^Ej2tW8OxNOIecSt4m}tji2O%YRJ;PJ!M|0*oO77*Rs&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x)u)IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j."(6U|{[UY@`lrCSJ`u0RHX!1z7f,v}n=GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz]iC<](:+FF?Ay'vX~h5QMF)0vaXk1sk@p
Zj).{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%`@:%H3wPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zip
{[ovg:6EpCT&'+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[F1F=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{"G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{DZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iiP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI#<`O$o#4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=8QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\']3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKGs5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;2'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`:[K:CY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{57#+2,*%]>p~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0"v1r+9fv;5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ93#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B!H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|R6rB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 3):

## 15. Rail, 4 moved, 7 added

```
|${     'main'                \           "`.3i                                                 !|
| 9         if                                                                                   |
|  6        )                                                                                    |
|   a                          0                                                                 |
| echo                                                                                           |
|     #               12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                     02                      **                                 |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp 56#                                                                          |
|                    :";8<<print         10                                                      |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                            '                                                                   |
|}                                                   =                                           |
|puts+11                      ;      +                                    2                      |
```

#### Remaining pieces

```
L-^=v^Ej2W8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|*oO77*R&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z7,v}=GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](+FF?Ay'vX~5QMF)0vaXksk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zp
{[vg:6ECT&+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:$yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Here, have a `main`! >:D

[Esolangs page.](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Rail#Constants) I used the interpreter linked to at the bottom of the page.

In Rail, the instruction pointer is a train which follows tracks made out of instructions. The first line is just ignored (and unfortunately, has to contain `'main'`), so the rails start to the bottom right. Since I don't divert them the entire code goes in that direction, and is effectively just:

```
96ao#
```

which means, push a `9`, push a `6`, add them, print the top of the stack, end the program.

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 3):

## 18. Javascript, 3 moved, 10 added

```
|/**                       56#\.@                                                                |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                                                                             |
|   a                          0                                                                 |
| echo                                                                                           |
|     #               12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                            ${                                  |
|                                                             9                                  |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp                                                                              |
|              '                                                                                 |
|              10                                                                                |
|              !                                                                                 |
|              'main'"`.3i                                                                       |
|}             7   if                                =                                           |
|puts+11       O   )          ;      +          */        alert  (      022    )                 |
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2W8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|*o77*R&2 <c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z7,v}=GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](+FF?Ay'vX~5QMF)0vaXksk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zp
{[vg:6ECT&+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:$yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx: ,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWg   MuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4 |su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w. ASwmN U-~q"[XcWbqPnns
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UA sQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4 ?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

More octal fun. Here's the test snippet:

```js
/**                       56#\.@                                                                
                           :";8<<print                                                          
  6                                                                                             
   a                          0                                                                 
 echo                                                                                           
     #               12!$>{:                                                                    
                                                                                                
                                                                                                
                                                                                                
                                                                                                
                                                            ${                                  
                                                             9                                  
                                                                                                
             :Disp                                                                              
              '                                                                                 
              10                                                                                
              !                                                                                 
              'main'"`.3i                                                                       
}             7   if                                =                                           
puts+11       O   )          ;      +          */        alert  (      022    )
```

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 3):

## 21. Unvanquished (Daemon engine) scripting, 2 moved, 3 added

[Unvanquished](http://www.unvanquished.net/) is an FPS/RTS game with humans vs. aliens. It also has a built-in scripting system with such commands as performing mathematical operations, concatenating strings, conditionals, looping a variable over different values, and the ability to execute scripts from arbitrary files. Thus I think it is valid as a programming language

```
|/**                       56#\.@                                                                |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                  alertprint                                                 |
|                              0                                                                 |
|                                                                                                |
|     #               12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                            ${                                  |
|                                                             9                                  |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp                                                                              |
|              '                                                                                 |
|              10                                                                                |
|              !                                                                                 |
|              'main'"`.3i                                                                       |
|}             7   if                               a=                                           |
|puts+11       O   )          ;      +          */echo     21//20(      022-3  )                 |
```

**Remaining Pieces**

```
L-^=v^Ej2W8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|*o77*R&2<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z7,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](+FF?Ay'vX~5QMF)0vaXksk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zp
{[vg:6ECT&+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:$yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UAsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0hov{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Comment: Correctness verified.

Comment: If anybody wants to try this, you need to put the file in the the config folder (on Windows it was in Documents/My Games), bring up the console in-game with `~` and run `exec <filename>`.

Answer (score 2):

## 6. Pyth, 2 moved, 1 added

```
|6#                                        `.3i                                                 !|
|:"                                                                                              |
|                                                                                                |
|              #               $>                              0            <<                   |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|print                                02                      **         2                       |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp 5                                                                            |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
```

#### Remaining Pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2tW8OxNOIecSt4m} j O%YRJ;PJ!M|0*oO77*Rs&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x)u)IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|{[UY@`l CSJ`u0RHX!1z7f,v} =GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz] C<](:+FF?Ay'vX~h5QMF)0vaXk1sk@p
Zj).{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zip
{[ovg:6E CT&'+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[F1F=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI <`O$o 4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=8QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\']3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;2'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0"v1r+9fv;5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ93#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B!H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Uses the old restricted source trick that Pyth only executes the first line of its source code (note that the online interpreter does not act this way). Any value in Pyth not used for something else is automatically printed.

The `` #    `.3i `` runs a `while 1` with a `try .. except` block. The `` `.3 `` would print 0.3 as the string representation of .3 but it is prefixed by a space character, which suppresses printing. The call to i requires 2 arguments, but it receives one a not function that also gets no arguments, so an exception is thrown, and the loop breaks.

Comment: I think that is simply a bug in the compiler. For instance, the current compiler http://pyth.herokuapp.com/ can handle all lines

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 2):

## 8. CJam, 1 moved, 3 added

```
|                                       "`.3i                                                   !|
|)                                                                                               |
|                                                                                                |
|              #               $>                              0            <<                   |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|print                                02                      **         2                       |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp 56#                                                                          |
|                    :";8                                                                        |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
```

**Remaining pieces**:

```
L-^=v^Ej2tW8OxNOIecSt4m} j O%YRJ;PJ!M|0*oO77*Rs&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x)u)IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|{[UY@`l CSJ`u0RHX!1z7f,v} =GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz] C<](:+FF?Ay'vX~h5QMF)0vaXk1sk@p
Zj.{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zip
{[ovg:6E CT&'+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[F1F=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI <`O$o 4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\']3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;2'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0v1r+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ93#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B!H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Simply pads everything in a string, pops it and then puts 8 on stack which gets printed automatically.

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 2):

## 14. ><>, 3 moved, 1 added

```
|            '                \           "`.3i                                                 !|
|           if                                                                                   |
|           )                                                                                    |
|              #               0                                                                 |
|                                                                                                |
|                     12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                     02                      **                                 |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                             echo                                              ${               |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp 56#                                                                          |
|                    :";8<<print 9       10                                                      |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                            '                                                                   |
|}                                                   =                                           |
|puts+11                      ;      +                                    2                      |
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2W8OxNOI  St4m j O%YRJ;PJ!M| *oO77*R&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`l CSJ`u0RHX! z7,v} =GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz] C<]( +FF?Ay'vX~ 5QMF)0vaXksk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zp
{[ vg:6E CT& +vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-n[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI <`O$o 4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~  ]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?; 'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0v r+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

*([Esolang page for ><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish))*

Runs `en;` vertically. The first `'` causes a whole bunch of chars on the first row to be added, but they are ignored.

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 2):

## 16. Befunge-93, 2 moved, 2 added

```
|${     'main'"`.3i        56#\.@                                                               !|
| 9         if              :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6        )                                                                                    |
|   a                          0                                                                 |
| echo                                                                                           |
|     #               12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                     02                      **                                 |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp                                                                              |
|                                        10                                                      |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                            '                                                                   |
|}                                                   =                                           |
|puts+11                      ;      +                                    2                      |
```

**Remaining Pieces**

```
L-^=v^Ej2W8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|*oO77*R&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z7,v}=GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](+FF?Ay'vX~5QMF)0vaXksk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zp
{[vg:6ECT&+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:$yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 2):

## 19. Swift, 1 moved, 7 added

```
|/**                       56#\.@                                                                |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                  alert                                                      |
|   a                          0                                                                 |
| echo                                                                                           |
|     #               12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                            ${                                  |
|                                                             9                                  |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp                                                                              |
|              '                                                                                 |
|              10                                                                                |
|              !                                                                                 |
|              'main'"`.3i                                                                       |
|}             7   if                                =                                           |
|puts+11       O   )          ;      +          */        print  (      022-3  )                 |
```

**Remaining pieces**:

```
L-^=v^Ej2W8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|*o77*R&2 <c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z7,v}=GvRgk EZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](+FF?Ay'vX~5QMF)0vaXksk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%F Sw>u_ 4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zp
{[vg:6ECT&+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:$yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx: ,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY% W|@`z}]b
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWg   MuyVOjz=zS!1 2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4 |su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3 T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w. ASwmN U-~q"[XcWbqPnns
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UA sQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4 ?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

[You can try Swift online here](http://swiftstub.com/)

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 2):

## 20. ///, 0 moved, 3 added

```
|/**                       56#\.@                                                                |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                  alert                                                      |
|   a                          0                                                                 |
| echo                                                                                           |
|     #               12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                            ${                                  |
|                                                             9                                  |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp                                                                              |
|              '                                                                                 |
|              10                                                                                |
|              !                                                                                 |
|              'main'"`.3i                                                                       |
|}             7   if                                =                                           |
|puts+11       O   )          ;      +          */        print  (      022-3  )              /20|
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2W8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|*o77*R&2<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z7,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](+FF?Ay'vX~5QMF)0vaXksk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zp
{[vg:6ECT&+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:$yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UAsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

[Esolangs page for ///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////)

Comment: Links in the headline mess up the leaderboard ;)

Comment: Correctness verified. Very nice idea to make use of the leading `/`. :)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I was trying to fix the snippet but, why are you parsing the Markdown instead of HTML? Not sure I should really fix that because language names with subscripts or `[link](...) (version)` will still be messed.

Answer (score 2):

## 26. Beam, 4 moved, 5 added

[Beam](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beam) is a 2D esolang (just like ><> or Marbelous) with 9 pointers, the Beam, the Store and 7 Memories.

```
|iipsp25.     $            56#\.@                                                                |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                  alertprint                                                 |
|                             '0                                                                 |
|                             +                              #*                     $            |
|~                        }                                                                      |
|                     /** puts+11                                                                |
|                       12!$>{:                                                                  |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                             n                                                                  |
|                             '                              ${                                  |
|                             +                               9                                  |
|                            :Disp                                                               |
|                             '                                                                  |
|                             10                                                                 |
|                             !                                                                  |
|                             'main'"`.3i                                                        |
|                             7   if                                                             |
|                             O   )                 a=                                           |
|                             ;           xx    */echo     21//20(      022-3  )    xcdddk*#p 23$|
```

**Remaining Pieces**:

```
-^=v^EjW8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|o77R&2<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z7,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](FF?AyvX~5QMF)0vaX sk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@t]z
{[vg:6ECT&vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT % [VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`: yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FI :,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_'1N {G2&j6 UWt_#%`sTt2 C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^ ;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QU.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYP 9
8A3 P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
dZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`( y+UAsQ=?KE07=\F VN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8< 'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0hov{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^w N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O .y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,s X'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

**How it works**

The program follows an L shape from the first `i` to `\` on the first row then to the `!` down the `\` then back to `\` and `i`.

Whenever it encounters `:`, it outputs the value of the Beam. `+` increments that value.

The first time `:` is hit, that value is `2` so that is printed. Then that value becomes `3` when it hits `!` . By this time, the value of Store becomes `3` too. On the way back, when it hits `n`, the value of both beam and store are `4` so the flow reverses back to `!` making the value `6` and `5` respectively, this time, the flow passes `n`, goes to `:` and prints `6` then terminates at `i`. STDOUT has 2 numbers back to back - `26`

[You can try Beam here](http://eso.mroman.ch/beam/)

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Ruby, 0 moved, 8 added

```
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                              $>                                           <<                   |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                     0                       **                                 |
|                                                 0                                              |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2tW8OxNOIecSt4m}tji2O%YRJ;PJ!M|0*oO77*Rs&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x)u)IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j."(6U|{[UY@`lrCSJ`u0RHX!1z7f,v}n=GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz]iC<](:+FF?Ay'vX~h5QMF)0vaXk1sk@p
Zj).{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%`@:%H3wPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zip
{[ovg:6EpCT&'+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[F1F=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{"G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{!m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^2mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{DZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iiP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI#<`O$o#4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=8QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\']3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKGs5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;2'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`:[K:CY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{57#+2,*%]>p~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0"v1r+9fv;5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ93#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B!H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|R6rB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Since the first two non-empty lines end with binary operators, the lines are continued, so the above code is identical to

```
$><<0**0
```

`$><<` is a golfy form of `print` and `0**0` happens to evaluate to `1` in Ruby.

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 3. Unlambda, 1 moved, 4 added

```
|`.3i                                                                                           !|
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                              $>                                           <<                   |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                     0                       **                                 |
|                         2                       0                                              |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2tW8OxNOIecSt4m}tj2O%YRJ;PJ!M|0*oO77*Rs&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x)u)IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|{[UY@`lrCSJ`u0RHX!1z7f,v}n=GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz]iC<](:+FF?Ay'vX~h5QMF)0vaXk1sk@p
Zj).{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zip
{[ovg:6EpCT&'+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[F1F=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{"G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{DZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iiP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI#<`O$o#4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=8QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\']3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKGs5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;2'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`:[K:CY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{57#+2,*%]>p~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0"v1r+9fv;5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ93#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B!H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|R6rB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Comment: Correctness verified (using the interpreter at [Anarchy Golf](http://golf.shinh.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

## 4. Python 2, 3 moved, 8 added

```
|                      #                   `.3i                                                 !|
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|              #               $>                              0            <<                   |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|print                                02                      **         2                       |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2tW8OxNOIecSt4m} j O%YRJ;PJ!M|0*oO77*Rs&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x)u)IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|{[UY@`l CSJ`u0RHX!1z7f,v} =GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz] C<](:+FF?Ay'vX~h5QMF)0vaXk1sk@p
Zj).{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zip
{[ovg:6E CT&'+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[F1F=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{"G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{DZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iiP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI <`O$o 4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=8QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\']3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKGs5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;2'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`:[K:CY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{57#+2,*%]>p~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0"v1r+9fv;5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ93#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B!H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|R6rB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Note that a leading zero means *octal*, but octal 2 is just 2 anyway.

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 5. TI-Basic, 0 moved, 8 added

```
|:"                    #                   `.3i                                                 !|
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|              #               $>                              0            <<                   |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|print                                02                      **         2                       |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp 5                                                                            |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
```

#### Remaining Pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2tW8OxNOIecSt4m} j O%YRJ;PJ!M|0*oO77*Rs&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x)u)IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|{[UY@`l CSJ`u0RHX!1z7f,v} =GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz] C<](:+FF?Ay'vX~h5QMF)0vaXk1sk@p
Zj).{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zip
{[ovg:6E CT&'+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[F1F=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI <`O$o 4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=8QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\']3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;2'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0"v1r+9fv;5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ93#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B!H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|R6rB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

`:"` comments all the code until the next `:`.

Comment: What kind of calculator is this supposed to work on? I couldn't find any backtick character on mine...

Comment: I found it [exists in the character set](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/83lgfont#60) but how do I type it in?

Comment: Also, unless I have a bug in my CJam script in you forgot to remove the characters from the second set. And I count 8 new characters. Please fix these issues.

Comment: I think this better be deleted rather than making other answers to wait.

Comment: Okay, here is what I'm gonna do. I'll fix the technical issues for you, and give you the benefit of the doubt for the backtick for now, so the challenge can continue. If the backtick turns out to be invalid, please invalidate your headline and/or delete your answer to remove it from the leaderboard.

Comment: Correctness verified.

Comment: @feersum You would probably have to create a small app in TI-assembly that allows you to type lower case letters and special symbols.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I apologize for my counting mistake. The script showed `Added character: :` only once. I was a little pressed on time so I didn't double check.

Answer (score 1):

## 9. Perl, 2 moved, 1 added

```
|                                       "`.3i                                                   !|
|)                                                                                               |
|                                                                                                |
|              #               $>                              0                                 |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                     02                      **         2                       |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp 56#                                                                          |
|                    :";8<<print 9                                                               |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
```

**Remaining Pieces**

```
L-^=v^Ej2tW8OxNOIecSt4m} j O%YRJ;PJ!M|0*oO77*Rs&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x)u)IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|{[UY@`l CSJ`u0RHX!1z7f,v} =GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz] C<](:+FF?Ay'vX~h5QMF)0vaXk1sk@p
Zj.{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zip
{[ovg:6E CT&'+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[F1F=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI <`O$o 4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\']3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;2'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0v1r+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B!H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 10. Bash, 0 moved, 9 added

```
|    :     '                            "`.3i                                                   !|
|)                                                                                               |
|                                                                                                |
|              #               $>                              0                                 |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                     02                      **         2                       |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp 56#                                                                          |
|                    :";8<<print 9                                                               |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                            '                                                                   |
|                                                                                                |
|echo 10                                                                                         |
```

**Remaining Pieces**

```
L-^=v^Ej2tW8OxNOI  St4m} j O%YRJ;PJ!M| *oO77*Rs&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x)u)IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|{[UY@`l CSJ`u0RHX! z7f,v} =GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz] C<]( +FF?Ay'vX~ 5QMF)0vaXk1sk@p
Zj.{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zip
{[ vg:6E CT& +vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[F1F=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI <`O$o 4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\ ]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;2'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0v1r+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B!H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

### 11. TCL, 3 moved, 10 added

```
|if 0 {:     '                            "`.3i                                                 !|
|)                                                                                               |
|                                                                                                |
|              #               $>                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                     02                      **         2                       |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp 56#                                                                          |
|                    :";8<<print 9  echo 10                                                      |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                            '                                                                   |
|}                                                                                               |
|puts 11                                                                                         |
```

### Remaining pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2W8OxNOI  St4m j O%YRJ;PJ!M| *oO77*R&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`l CSJ`u0RHX! z7,v} =GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz] C<]( +FF?Ay'vX~ 5QMF)0vaXksk@
Zj.{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zp
{[ vg:6E CT& +vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI <`O$o 4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\ ]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;2'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0v1r+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B!H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

### 12. Mouse, 3 moved, 3 added

```
|12!$>{:     '                            "`.3i                                                 !|
|           if                                                                                   |
|           )                                                                                    |
|              #               0                                                                 |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                     02                      **         2                       |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp 56#                                                                          |
|                    :";8<<print 9  echo 10                                                      |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                            '                                                                   |
|}                                                                                               |
|puts 11                                                                                         |
```

### Remaining pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2W8OxNOI  St4m j O%YRJ;PJ!M| *oO77*R&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`l CSJ`u0RHX! z7,v} =GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz] C<]( +FF?Ay'vX~ 5QMF)0vaXksk@
Zj.{+l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zp
{[ vg:6E CT& +vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
;&-n[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4+u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5{:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns=
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI <`O$o 4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\ ]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?; 'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC$>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0v r+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Use [this interpreter](http://mouse.davidgsimpson.com/mouse79/mouse79_c.txt).

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 13. PHP, 3 moved, 6 added

```
|echo  ${    '                            "`.3i                                                 !|
|           if                                                                                   |
|           )                                                                                    |
|              #               0                                                                 |
|                                                                                                |
|                     12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                     02                      **                                 |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp 56#                                                                          |
|                    :";8<<print 9       10                                                      |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                            '                                                                   |
|}                                                   =                                           |
|puts+11                             +                                    2      ;               |
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2W8OxNOI  St4m j O%YRJ;PJ!M| *oO77*R&2*<c"KI7e%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`l CSJ`u0RHX! z7,v} =GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz] C<]( +FF?Ay'vX~ 5QMF)0vaXksk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zp
{[ vg:6E CT& +vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=66},hL~;a`:$'yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-n[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{ m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^ mn@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI <`O$o 4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9am-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~\ ]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5i^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?; 'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU3.4G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0v r+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1@[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':B H8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Run with `php -r`.

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 17. Fission, 4 moved, 2 added

```
|${                        56#\.@                                                                |
| 9                         :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                                                                             |
|   a                          0                                                                 |
| echo                                                                                           |
|     #               12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                     02                      **                                 |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp                                                                              |
|              '                                                                                 |
|              10                                                                                |
|              !                                                                                 |
|              'main'"`.3i                                                                       |
|}             7   if                                =                                           |
|puts+11       O   )          ;      +                                    2                      |
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
L-^=v^Ej2W8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|*o77*R&2*<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z7,v}=GvRgkrEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](+FF?Ay'vX~5QMF)0vaXksk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FnSw>u_-4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zp
{[vg:6ECT&+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:$yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FIx:l,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%3W|@`z}]bp
4_'1Nx{G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2xC}s1P8J<gV24_RWge/aMuyVOjz=zS!1i2s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4/|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3tT8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.(ASwmN)U-~q"[XcWbqPnns
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(dy+UArsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4t?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
2&9egng~L#\QkfMG?S/n@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv0!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<d'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0ho/v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wd2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz2&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,scX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:h1wR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

[Esolangs page for Fission.](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fission)

I didn't find a way to compile the interpreter under Linux (There was a way getting the `arc4random` function but it only worked for pure C program). So I simply replaced the line `atom.dir = (atom.dir + arc4random() % 3 + 3) & 3;` in `Mirror.cpp` with `assert(false);`.

Comment: Correctness verified. (accidentally deleted the comment along with the others)

Answer (score 1):

## 22. Deadfish x, 0 moved, 8 added

```
|/**                       56#\.@                                                                |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                  alertprint                                                 |
|                              0                                                                 |
|                                                                                                |
|     #               12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                            ${                                  |
|                                                             9                                  |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp                                                                              |
|              '                                                                                 |
|              10                                                                                |
|              !                                                                                 |
|              'main'"`.3i                                                                       |
|}             7   if                               a=                                           |
|puts+11       O   )          ;      +    xx    */echo     21//20(      022-3  )    xcdddk       |
```

**Remaining Pieces**

```
L-^=v^Ej2W8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|*o77*R&2<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a#<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z7,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](+FF?Ay'vX~5QMF)0vaX sk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]zp
{[vg:6ECT&+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:$yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FI :,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_'1N {G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2 C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5Qn3U.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`( y+UAsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8< 'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0hov{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^w 2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,s X'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

*([Esolang page](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish_x))*

It's the Deadfish family, good for nothing but printing numbers! Unlike the [original Deadfish](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish), Deadfish x ignores invalid chars (in the Python interpreter at least), so that's why it was used instead.

`x` is increment, `k` is output, `c` is square and `d` is decrement. `echo` already has a `c` but no other char out of `xkd` is on the board, so I just added the rest. The `D` from `Disp` sets the accumulator to zero, but luckily that's before the `c`.

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 23. Brat, 2 moved, 6 added

```
|#*                        56#\.@                                                                |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                  alertprint                                                 |
|                              0                                                                 |
|                   /**                                                                          |
|                     12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                            ${                                  |
|                                                             9                                  |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp                                                                              |
|              '                                                                                 |
|              10                                                                                |
|              !                                                                                 |
|              'main'"`.3i                                                                       |
|}             7   if                               a=                                           |
|puts+11       O   )          ;      +    xx    */echo     21//20(      022-3  )    xcdddk*#p 23 |
```

**Remaining Pieces**:

```
L-^=v^EjW8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|o77R&2<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z7,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](+FF?Ay'vX~5QMF)0vaX sk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]z
{[vg:6ECT&+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT~%$[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:$yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FI :,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_'1N {G2&j6$UWt_#%`sTt2 C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^p;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QnU.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYPp9
8A3iP[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`( y+UAsQ=?KE07=\FsVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8< 'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0hov{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^w 2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_Oi.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,s X'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

[Try Brat here](http://try.brat-lang.org/#)

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 24. 3var, 1 moved, 9  added

```
|iipsp        $            56#\.@                                                                |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                  alertprint                                                 |
|                              0                                                                 |
|                   /**                                      #*                     $            |
|~                    12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                            ${                                  |
|                                                             9                                  |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp                                                                              |
|              '                                                                                 |
|              10                                                                                |
|              !                                                                                 |
|              'main'"`.3i                                                                       |
|}             7   if                               a=                                           |
|puts+11       O   )          ;      +    xx    */echo     21//20(      022-3  )    xcdddk*#p 23$|
```

**Remaining Pieces**:

```
L-^=v^EjW8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|o77R&2<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z7,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](+FF?Ay'vX~5QMF)0vaX sk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]z
{[vg:6ECT&+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT % [VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`: yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FI :,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_'1N {G2&j6 UWt_#%`sTt2 C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^ ;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QnU.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYP 9
8A3 P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
d.ZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`( y+UAsQ=?KE07=\F VN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>5?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8< 'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0hov{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^w 2N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O .y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,s X'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

(*[Esolang page for 3var](http://esolangs.org/wiki/3var)*)

Works sort of like the Deadfish solution, but instead I print each digit separately, allowing for a simple `iipsp` to mean `inc inc print square print`. `$` is the multiline comment syntax for 3var, while `~` is a single line comment.

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 25. FALSE, 0 moved, 3 added

I tested it in this [Javascript interpreter](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/false-js.html). I guess the idea is that it gives up upon encountering the `#`, which is supposed to form a while loop if it follows two blocks.

```
|iipsp25.     $            56#\.@                                                                |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                  alertprint                                                 |
|                              0                                                                 |
|                   /**                                      #*                     $            |
|~                    12!$>{:                                                                    |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                                                                |
|                                                            ${                                  |
|                                                             9                                  |
|                                                                                                |
|             :Disp                                                                              |
|              '                                                                                 |
|              10                                                                                |
|              !                                                                                 |
|              'main'"`.3i                                                                       |
|}             7   if                               a=                                           |
|puts+11       O   )          ;      +    xx    */echo     21//20(      022-3  )    xcdddk*#p 23$|
```

**Remaining Pieces**

```
-^=v^EjW8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|o77R&2<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z7,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](+FF?Ay'vX~5QMF)0vaX sk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZpOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@'t]z
{[vg:6ECT&+vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT % [VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`: yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-[FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FI :,f_LT@sV[]HF@2*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_'1N {G2&j6 UWt_#%`sTt2 C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^ ;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QnU.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYP 9
8A3 P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
dZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`( y+UAsQ=?KE07=\F VN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8< 'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0hov{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^w N<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O .y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,s X'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Comment: Correctness verified

Comment: This answer is missing the first capital `L` in the remaining pieces. But since the challenge has already moved on and we probably won't run out of `L`s any time soon (and won't be able to use up all pieces either), we will continue without that `L`.

Answer (score 1):

## 27. dc, 2 moved, 5 added

```
|            [$            56#\.@                                                                |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                  alertprint                                                 |
|                             '0                                                                 |
|                             +                              #*                     $            |
|~                        }                                                                      |
|                     /** puts+11                                                                |
|                       12!$>{:                                                                  |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                             n                                                                  |
|                             '                              ${                                  |
|                             +                               9                                  |
|                            :Disp                                                               |
|                             '                                                                  |
|                             10                                                                 |
|                             !                                                                  |
|                             'main'"`.3i                   23$                                  |
|                             7   if                 iipsp25.                                    |
|                             O   )                 a=                                           |
|                             ;           xx    */echo     21//20(      022-3  )    xcdddk*#p]27p|
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
-^=v^EjW8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|o77R&2<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](FF?AyvX~5QMF)0vaXsk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8Kay&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@tz
{[vg:6ECT&vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH/^DL"RkT%[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:yty.W[g2OWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5yda8J$+`N;:FI:,f_LT@sV[]HF@*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_'1N{G2&j6UWt_#%`sTt2C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@W/k@.YLbKxS:g9?J^;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QU.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,*4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(a*k_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYP9
8A3P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
dZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(y+UAsQ=?KE07=\FVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0hov{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wN<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,sX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Because I guess someone will want to do Brainfuck before it is too late...

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 28. ooRexx, 1 moved, 9 added

```
|          /*[$            56#\.@                                                                |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                  alertprint                                                 |
|                             '0                                                                 |
|                             +                              #*                     $            |
|~                        }   xcdddk*#p]27p                                                      |
|                     /** puts+11                                                                |
|                       12!$>{:                                                                  |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                             n                                                                  |
|                             '                              ${                                  |
|                             +                               9                                  |
|                            :Disp                                                               |
|                             '                                                                  |
|                             10                                                                 |
|                             !                                                                  |
|                             'main'"`.3i                   23$                                  |
|                             7   if                 iipsp25.                                    |
|                             O   )                 a=                                           |
|                             ;           xx    */echo     21//20(      022-3  )    */say 28     |
```

**Remaining Pieces**:

```
-^=v^EjW8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;PJ!M|o77R&2<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](FF?AyvX~5QMF)0vaXsk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8K&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@tz
{[vg:6ECT&vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH^DL"RkT%[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:yty.W[gOWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5ydaJ$+`N;:FI:,f_LT@V[]HF@*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_'1N{G2&j6UWt_#%`sTt2C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@Wk@.YLbKxS:g9?J^;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QU.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR29'L?n\gk,4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9nrz8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(ak_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2niIYP9
8A3P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
dZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(y+UAsQ=?KE07=\FVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO@6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0hov{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wN<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
(h$i3`,sX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

[ooRexx docs](http://www.oorexx.org/docs/)

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 29. Mathematica, 4 moved, 9 added

```
|Print @29(*/say            56#\.@                                                               |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                  alertprint                                                 |
|                             '0                                                                 |
|                             +                                                     $            |
|~                        }   xcdddk*#p]27p                                                      |
|                     /** puts+11                                                                |
|                       12!$>{:                                                                  |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                             n                                                                  |
|                             '                              ${                                  |
|        /*[$                 +                               9                                  |
|                            :Disp                                                               |
|                             '                                                                  |
|                             10                                                                 |
|                             !                                                                  |
|                             'main'"`.3i                   23$                                  |
|                             7   if                 iipsp25.                                    |
|                             O   )                 a=                                           |
|                             ;           xx    */echo     21//20(      022-3             28  #*)|
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
-^=v^EjW8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;J!M|o77R&<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a<E6<yv5O*$kL):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](FF?AyvX~5QMF)0vaXsk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8K&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@tz
{[vg:6ECT&vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH^DL"RkT%[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:yty.W[gOWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5ydaJ$+`N;:FI:,f_LT@V[]HF@*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_'1N{G2&j6UWt_#%`sT2C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@Wk@.YLbKxS:g9?J^;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iM)f4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QU.v5LF;HXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR2'L?n\gk,4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"3T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9z8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoE(ak_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!2(6gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2nIYP9
8A3P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
dZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(y+UAsQ=?KE07=\FVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui*5^0^fO6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0hov{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wN<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
h$i3`,sX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Mathematica block-comments are written as `(* ... *)`.

Comment: Correctness Verified

Answer (score 1):

## 30. DWScript, 1 moved, 9 added

```
|PrintLn(30);    (*@29(*/say56#\.@                                                               |
|                           :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                                  alertprint                                                 |
|                             '0                                                                 |
|                             +                                                     $            |
|~                        }   xcdddk*#p]27p                                                      |
|                     /** puts+11                                                                |
|                       12!$>{:                                                                  |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                             n                                                                  |
|                             '                              ${                                  |
|        /*[$                 +                               9                                  |
|                            :Disp                                                               |
|                             '                                                                  |
|                             10                                                                 |
|                             !                                                                  |
|                             'main'"`.3i                   23$                                  |
|                             7   if                 iipsp25.                                    |
|                             O   )                 a=                                           |
|                             ;           xx    */echo     21//20(      022-3             28  #*)|
```

**Remaining Pieces**:

```
-^=v^EjW8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;J!M|o77R&<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a<E6<yv5O*$k):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](FF?AyvX~5QMF)0vaXsk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8K&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@tz
{[vg:6ECT&vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH^DL"RkT%[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:yty.W[gOWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5ydaJ$+`N;:FI:,f_LT@V[]HF@*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_'1N{G2&j6UWt_#%`sT2C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@Wk@.YLbKxS:g9?J^;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iMf4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QU.v5LFHXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR2'L?\gk,4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9z8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoEak_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!26gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2nIYP9
8A3P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
dZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(y+UAsQ=?KE7=\FVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xui5^0^fO6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0hov{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wN<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
h$i3`,sX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

[Some](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:DWScript) [links](http://www.delphitools.info/dwscript/). Basically, DWScript also has the same block comments as Mathematica and `PrintLn();` prints.

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 31. Deadfish~, 1 moved, 3 added

No one protested, so you're getting more Deadfish variants.

Note: To use the [interpreter](https://github.com/craigmbooth/deadfish/blob/master/deadfish.py), you need to call the `deadfish` function, not the `deadfish_cli` which is set to run if the file is executed.

```
|PrintLn(30);    (*@29(*/say56#\.@                                                             ${|
|                           :";8<<print                                                         9|
|  6                           i      alertprint                                                 |
|                             '0                                                                 |
|                             +                                                     $            |
|~                        }oh xcdddk*#p]27p                                                      |
|                     /** puts+11                                                                |
|                       12!$>{:                                                                  |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                             n                                                                  |
|                             '                                                                  |
|        /*[$                 +                                                                  |
|                            :Disp                                                               |
|                             '                                                                  |
|                             10                                                                 |
|                             !                                                                  |
|                             'main'"`.3i                   23$                                  |
|                             7   if                 iipsp25.                                    |
|                             O   )                 a=                                           |
|                             ;           xx    */echo     21//20(      022-3             28  #*)|
```

**Remaining Pieces**

```
-^=v^EjW8OxNOISt4mjO%YRJ;J!M|o77R&<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y@`x))IBk%_a<E6<yv5O*$k):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](FF?AyvX~5QMF)0vaXsk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8K&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZOI$7\Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@tz
{[vg:6ECT&vU4Heb^;}0AV|?}M0rAH^DL"RkT%[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~;`:yty.W[gOWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5ydaJ$+`N;:FI:,f_LT@V[]HF@*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_'1N{G2&j6UWt_#%`sT2C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@Wk@.YLbKxS:g9?J^;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iMf4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QU.v5LFHXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR2'L?\gk,4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9z8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoEak_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!26gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2nIYP9
8A3P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
dZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(y+UAsQ=?KE7=\FVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xu5^0^fO6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wN<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
h$i3`,sX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Comment: This looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

## 32. Hack, 5 moved, 7 added

```
|@ ${ '          (*@29(*/say56#\.@                                                               |
|   9                       :";8<<print                                                          |
|  6                           i      alertprint                                                 |
|                            \'0                                                                 |
|                             +                                                     $            |
|~                        }oh xcdddk*#p]27p                                                      |
|                     /** puts+11                                                                |
|                       12!$>{:                  PrintLn(30);                                    |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                             n                                                                  |
|                             '        };                                                        |
|        /*[$                 +                                                                  |
|                            :Disp                                                               |
|                             '                                                                  |
|                             10                                                                 |
|                             !                                                                  |
|               23$           'main'"`.3i                                                        |
|        iipsp25.             7   if                                                             |
|       a=                    O   )                                                              |
|   */echo 28  + 4            ;   #*)     xx               21//20(      022-3                    |
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
-^=v^EjW8OxNOIStmjO%YRJ;J!M|o77R&<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y`x))IBk%_a<E6<yv5O*$k):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RHX!z,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](FF?AyvX~5QMF)0vaXsk@
Zj.{l;PBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8K&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZOI$7Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@tz
{[vg:6ECT&vU4Heb^;0AV|?}M0rAH^DL"RkT%[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~`:yty.W[gOWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5ydaJ$`N;:FI:,f_LT@V[]HF@*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_1N{G2&j6UWt_#%`sT2C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12s@`Q#@^~@Wk@.YLbKxS:g9?J^;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS5G4}kx_iMf4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QU.v5LFHXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'3$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR2'L?\gk,4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9z8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoEak_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQ3E_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!26gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2nIYP9
8A3P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
dZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(y+UAsQ=?KE7=\FVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xu5^0^fO6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wN<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
h$i3`,sX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

http://3v4l.org/RGaXk

This was previously a PHP script which only compiled on PHP4 and fatalled on PHP5, but since that's not allowed I'll use a language which is compatible with PHP but with a different name :-p

I did all the manipulations manually, so sorry if I've made a typo somewhere...  :-/

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 33. AutoHotkey, 4 moved, 10 added

```
|;    '          (*@29(*/say56#\.@                                                              6|
|MsGBOX 33     ;            :";8<<print                                                          |
|/*[$                          i      alertprint                                                 |
|                            \'0                                                                 |
|                             +                                                     $            |
|~                        }oh xcdddk*#p]27p                                                      |
|                     /** puts+11                                                                |
|                       12!$>{:                  PrintLn(30);                                    |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                             n                                                                  |
|                             '        };                                                        |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                            :Disp                                                               |
|                             '                                                                  |
|                             10                                                                 |
|                             !                                                                  |
|               23$           'main'"`.3i                                                        |
|        iipsp25.             7   if                                                             |
|       a=                    O   )                                                            ${|
|  @*/echo 28  + 4            ;   #*)     xx               21//20(      022-3                   9|
```

**Remaining Pieces**

```
-^=v^EjW8xNOIStmjO%YRJ;J!|o77R&<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y`x))Ik%_a<E6<yv5O*$k):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RH!z,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](FF?AyvX~5QMF)0vaXsk@
Zj.{lPBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8K&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZOI$7Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@tz
{[vg:6ECT&vU4Heb^;0AV|?}M0rAH^DL"RkT%[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~`:yty.W[gOWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5ydaJ$`N:FI:,f_LT@V[]HF@*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_1N{G2&j6UWt_#%`sT2C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12@`Q#@^~@Wk@.YLbKxS:g9?J^;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS54}kx_iMf4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QU.v5LFHXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR2'L?\gk,4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9z8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoEak_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQE_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!26gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2nIYP9
8A3P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
dZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(y+UAsQ=?KE7=\FVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbMc^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv)
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8n#mD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xu5^0^fO6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<'Vby]8kEHh04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?;'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z`:k=C\0v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wN<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfU34G3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*eT9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O.y8ofX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
h$i3`,sX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 34. Zsh, 2 moved, 10 added

```
|echo 34;21//20()(*@29(*/say56#\.@                                                              6|
|       33     ;            :";8<<print                                                          |
|                              i      alertprint                                                 |
|                            \'0               ;    '                                            |
|                             +                MsGBOX                               $            |
|~                        }oh xcdddk*#p]27p    /*[$                                              |
|                     /** puts+11                                                                |
|                       12!$>{:                  PrintLn(30);                                    |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                             n                                                                  |
|                             '        };                                                        |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                            :Disp                                                               |
|                             '                                                                  |
|                             10                                                                 |
|                             !                                                                  |
|               23$           'main'"`.3i                                                        |
|        iipsp25.             7   if                                                             |
|       a=                    O   )                                                            ${|
|  @*/echo 28  + 4            ;  `#*)#    xx                            022-3                   9|
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
-^=v^EjW8xNOIStmjO%YRJ;J!|o77R&<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y`x))Ik%_a<E6<yv5O*$k):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RH!z,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](FF?AyvX~5QMF)0vaXsk@
Zj.{lPBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8K&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZOI$7Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@tz
{[vg:6ECT&vU4Heb^;0AV|?}M0rAH^DL"RkT%[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~`:yty.W[gOWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5ydaJ$`N:FI:,f_LT@V[]HF@*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_1N{G2&j6UWt_#%`sT2C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12@`Q#@^~@Wk@.YLbKxS:g9?J^;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS54}kx_iMf4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QU.v5LFHXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR2'L?\gk,4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9z8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoEak_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQE_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;3LI!26gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2nIYP9
8A3P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
dZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(y+UAsQ=?KE7=\FVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbM^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8nmD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xu5^0^fO6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<'Vby]8kEH04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux5)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z:k=C\0v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wN<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfUG3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*T9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O.y8fX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
h$i3`,sX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Comment: Correctness verified.

Answer (score 1):

## 35. TECO, 1 moved, 5 added

```
|35=EX34;21//20()(*@29(*/say56#\.@                                                              6|
|       33     ;            :";8<<print                                                          |
|                              i      alertprint                                                 |
|                            \'0               ;    '                                            |
|                             +                MsGBOX                               $            |
|~                        }oh xcdddk*#p]27pecho/*[$                                              |
|                     /** puts+11                                                                |
|                       12!$>{:                  PrintLn(30);                                    |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                             n                                                                  |
|                             '        };                                                        |
|                             +                                                                  |
|                            :Disp                                                               |
|                             '                                                                  |
|                             10                                                                 |
|                             !                                                                  |
|               23$           'main'"`.3i                                                        |
|        iipsp25.             7   if                                                             |
|       a=                    O   )                                                            ${|
|  @*/echo 28  + 4            ;  `#*)#    xx                            022-3                   9|
```

**Remaining Pieces**

```
-^v^jW8xNOIStmjO%YRJ;J!|o77R&<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y`x))Ik%_a<E6<yv5O*$k):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RH!z,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](FF?AyvX~5QMF)0vask@
Zj.{lPBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8K&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZOI$7Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@tz
{[vg:6ECT&vU4Heb^;0AV|?}M0rAH^DL"RkT%[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~`:yty.W[gOWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5ydaJ$`N:FI:,f_LT@V[]HF@*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_1N{G2&j6UWt_#%`sT2C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12@`Q#@^~@Wk@.YLbKxS:g9?J^;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS54}kx_iMf4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QU.v5LFHXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR2'L?\gk,4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9z8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoEak_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQE_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;LI!26gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2nIYP9
8A3P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
dZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(y+UAsQ=?KE7=\FVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbM^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>?hi{5<9FtWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8nmD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xu5^0^fO6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<'Vby]8kEH04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z:k=C\0v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wN<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfUG3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*T9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O.y8fX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vuc"
h$i3`,sX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWfq)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.s#G6A.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@L3KrQv
```

Comment: Correctness verified (using `mung` in the [Linux version](http://almy.us/teco.html)).

Answer (score 0):

## 36. bc, 1 moved, 7 added

```
|36# 35=EX34;21//20()(*@29(*/say56#\.@                                                          6|
|  quit     33     ;            :";8<<print                                                      |
|                                  i      alertprint                                             |
|                                \'0               ;    '                                        |
|                                 +                MsGBOX                           $            |
|~                            }oh xcdddk*#p]27pecho/*[$                                          |
|                         /** puts+11                                                            |
|                           12!$>{:              PrintLn(30);                                    |
|                                 +                                                              |
|                                 n                                                              |
|                                 '    };                                                        |
|                                 +                                                              |
|                                :Disp                                                           |
|                                 '                                                              |
|                                 10                                                             |
|                                 !                                                              |
|               23$               'main'"`.3i                                                    |
|        iipsp25.                 7   if                                                         |
|       a=                        O   )                                                        ${|
|  @*/echo 28  + 4                ;  `#*)#xx                            022-3                   9|
```

#### Remaining pieces:

```
-^v^jW8xNOIStmjO%YRJ;J!|o77R&<c"KIe%FY^?I=];Y`x))Ik%_a<E6<yv5O*$k):
KNGq)2Wa%b)j"(6U|[UY@`lCSJ`u0RH!z,v}=GvRgkEZ=YT:4H44bz]C<](FF?AyvX~5QMF)0vask@
Zj.{lPBKHABvEP%FSw>u_4B^AI8K&5]vXZJ{fCF]UVZ<!ZOI$7Y%@:%HwPsX-`/l]ZZ?Q/d`\M<T@tz
{[vg:6ECT&vU4Heb^;0AV|?}M0rAH^DL"RkT%[VUlM]-&We4(P=6},hL~`:yty.W[gOWcL~b:Ryj0*eN<
&-FF=oh0k[NI!xS"]pA@Y;K}'=ekG5ydaJ$`N:FI:,f_LT@V[]HF@*vl?|q"GL1j&%e(CyYPqY%W|@`z}]b
4_1N{G2&j6UWt_#%`sT2C}s1P8J<gV24_RWgMuyVOjz=zS!12@`Q#@^~@Wk@.YLbKxS:g9?J^;7ju?B\yC5
x,ZApKS54}kx_iMf4|su>=[{XSV#{,j5QU.v5LFHXs%DYm4'+efmU;\}f6j$SFCRC`Gsd37:'$q=bs;lvsW0Yj^:-
I[94@I|.IpR=}4KB4ZG4>8PR2'L?\gk,4X[-%T`\FC)jj0jl_x<xL8E:G2-"T8&E}"sE+SH[7jR%@V)a{m8K>.rAO
2[dq7GX9z8p4}^n@q|dF%<.Tl8)Dk?O.<UoEak_=4u!h$^bVd:$jS#EHFh@Z=y=ib^~/~lEJ^SQE_t#&^IOov7v8
~j#I#OHgxg{ZDyCsq-(GVq}HbiG,JV?eJ~5wJ;bSt@;LI!26gIT92>}`_dw;YF@ccTIEz\Gu@2(}J2I1"S{R(2nIYP9
8A3P[*!SH2*SN8'`V?w4Ufx2HAz%{}FlUdH31TJ5:ge^N91^;9Gj`Uqf'$_|8P"kHR1w.ASwmNU-~q"[XcWbqPnns
dZoPJ}$Xc2lA>HN28`(y+UAsQ=?KE7=\FVN(#?&hRabS%BVI<`O$o4x5ZFFLGDcA4?&Eh~Z$oBWwNSNv`^;vO'
&9egng~L#\QkfMG?Sn@%-VA[?f9K&3"V%P#Sv!D<,GV:Z;3c&zFe^k&^0b7fAjvrbM^Lq7k$h=YL<h7<0\NK>~Q=uUv
4cI$.'b-RVS-=rom:=QR=c>9m-^5F[XGv>E/>|]~]3{r{kTc?ee1v=;I7]52#NE)~A;}!z>?h{5<9FWH6{VO_Y-Jy
Mw>{l8nmD,kl'8cG^.7sy=QqU-3~SKG5(.Ta]:-Vfr'NS$o*q:w6e$&7spk3{CFT'l_hGY0-0Xu5^0^fO6?2IdCn_C
lPKaJ6]0t!u>v8<'Vby]8kEH04p(YI)&7w82BrGB3PkI,s+%7ux)gau`G!8F8hLa4[lfD55Xf3Hqy*-K,?'fxH3JWYE
Z.[N`[KCY@TzKX4TMXsm{Xbd:B3)Gy[mlwnC>)z:k=C\0v{7#+2,*%]>~vI2^C:2DebJR>.ESw^wN<~]O9sOQ
`_yvIw&Ryf%JgT@W(G1wfUG3U}x1jKJzJY\S9n$2~P;F}*T9UXcTNBTrTs>~0v_O.y8fX6i5u$;'^"q][QhTb*gO[U
n'R0vr+9fv5G7Bg=D:c*a=1[}7}dYOO{Mz&@6`jnNq.QcBDM9Dd=R.*=MqZ3#'{AJJFqx<{qb':BH8ig1L%T\Vc"
h$i3`,sX'hqpbw"=nY`*Lu:hwR{+-`\^3cQkIWf)3?&p;~pvDW$o7\O|RrB2{PX.sGA.s<OA_,TI_b*&lO@LKrQv
```

Uninteresting.

Comment: Can someone verify this?